# How can I select a data if that data is not existing in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select a set of data from a table (`TableA`), but only if it's not in another table (`TableB`).

```
SELECT thisData FROM dbo.TableA WHERE thisData is not existing in dbo.TableB
```

I'm not really well versed in SQL.

Comment: What's the structure of the two tables? How do they link together?

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist different structures. But thisData from both tables have similar types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `not exists` condition:

```
SELECT  thisData 
FROM    dbo.TableA a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    TableB b
        WHERE   a.thisData = b.thisData
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do `EXCEPT`:

```
SELECT thisData FROM dbo.TableA
except
SELECT thisData FROM dbo.TableB
```

Or, a more general solution, `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from dbo.TableA ta
where not exists (select 1 from dbo.TableB tb
                  where tb.thiscolumn1 = ta.thiscolumn1

                  [  and tb.thiscolumn2 = ta.thiscolumn2  etc]

                  )
```

Comment: +1 Original idea with `except`.  I think `not exists (select *` would be a bit cleaner than the `select 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join and NULL check. This will only return the rows that don't exist in table b and is much more performant than doing multiple 'selects' and 'exists'.

```
SELECT a.thisData FROM dbo.TableA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b ON b.thisData = a.thisData
WHERE b.thisData IS NULL
```

Edit: if you need to compare multiple columns, you can achieve that as well

```
SELECT a.col1, a.col2, ... FROM dbo.TableA a
LEFT JOIN dbo.TableB b ON b.col1 = a.col1 AND b.col2 = a.col2 AND ...
WHERE b.col1 IS NULL
```